# Realm import problems

Tags: android, realm

I have queries why realm not support their own .realm file for import?

Why they not give any converter for .realm to CSV?

Why no option even java class directly?

I am stuck about importing existing schema.
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter is only for ios why realm not giving solution for all platform.
May I have at least sample csv file for importing in android studio

Comment: I do not understand the specific problem that you are trying to solve because the csv format / headers are not specified

Comment: I want to restore my Android app's realm schema with realm cloud database using android studio

Comment: I thought you just have to connect to the Realm with a SyncConfiguration and it should figure out the local schema based on that

Comment: thanks you saved my day! do you have idea about getting notification in background from realm android

Comment: Depends on what you mean by notification and by background

Comment: is there any method to get generated notification for specific records?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you help me on https://support.realm.io/support/tickets/731

Comment: It is possible if you run a Node backend that registers as global notifier listener to ROS and then send push notifications to devices based on that, but that's outside my scope, and I don't see the support tickets as I don't work for Realm :p